# No sound on 13.04 except when (un)plugging power chord

Tags: 13.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

The only sound working properly is the power-beep. If there's music playing and I unplug my laptop then I can hear it for that half a second that the power beep makes a sound, so it seems that something is blocking my audio from getting to the speakers.

I had this problem with 12.04 as well.

I've reloaded and reinstalled alsa/pulseaudio. All the alsamixer/pavucontrols look fine to me.

It briefly worked, when I first switched from unity to gnome-shell and when I upgraded from 12.04 to 13.04, but now I have the same problem.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently repeatedly turning it off and on again makes some kind of magic happen and now it's working again. \o/